# How to scale video to 3.5:1 without quality lose on Ubuntu?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, handbrake

I tried to use ffmpeg: `ffmpeg -i <input_file> -vf scale=3.5:1 <output_file>`, also tried `3,5` instead of `3.5`. But it tells that there is invalid size. I would appreciate any application, Handbrake for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i <input_file> -vf scale=3.5*iw:ih <output_file>
```

This command will apply the default encoding parameters, so specific settings will depend on output format.

You may wish to add `setsar=1` after the scale, so that players don't resize the video during playback.